# initializer fails to determine size of string in C++

Tags: c++

I wrote a program to remove spaces from string in c++. But when i compile this program i got two errors. They are `error: initializer fails to determine size of ‘str1’` and `error: array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer`.

Can any one show me the error of my code. I am new for C++. I mentioned my code below

```
#include <stack>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

char *delSpaces(char *str)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    while (str[i])
   {
    if (str[i] != ' ')
       str[j++] = str[i];
    i++;
   }
    str[j] = '\0';
    return str;
}

int main(){
    string s;
    cin >> s;
    char str1[]=s;  
    cout << delSpaces(str1);
}
```

Comment: `char str1[] = s;` - not valid C++. And there is no need to convert a std::string into a char array.

Comment: @NeilButterworth It is, you just need the right initializer `char foo[] = "works";`

Comment: @NeilButterworth `char always_has[] = "worked";`

Comment: @NeilButterworth i want take input from user. then how can i do so??

Comment: Why aren't you passing a `std::string` to `delSpaces`?

Comment: Yes, copy and paste failure.

Comment: Just use std::string and get rid of the char[]. By using char* ... you are making things more difficult and error prone.

Comment: @drescherjm can u show me it as a answer?

Comment: @NathanOliver can u show me how can i do it. Becuse this is my first cpp program.

Comment: The answer already tells you what to do here: ***I recommend changing your function to take a string argument by reference*** I guess you don't understand what that means.

Comment: @drescherjm yes it dont understand still my wrong place

Comment: change `char* delSpaces(char *str)` to `std::string delSpaces(std::string & str)` or  `std::string delSpaces(std::string str)` the second version will not change the original string. In both cases call it using `cout << delSpaces(s);` and get rid of the `char str1[]=s;`

Comment: @drescherjm now error is gone but in output is not accurate. After 1st space nothing print. output shows only to first space characters

Comment: Instead of `str[j] = '\0';` you want `str.resize(j);` http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/resize/

Comment: `cin >> s;` does not work with strings containing spaces (it extracts up to the first space). use std::getline() instead. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline The what is your name part of the example is what you want.

Comment: @drescherjm thank you very much friend..now it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't initialize a `char[]` buffer with a `std::string` object, that is why you are getting errors.

You would have to do something more like this instead:

```
char *str1 = new char[s.size()+1];
std::copy(s.begin(), s.end(), str1);
str1[s.size()] = '\0';
std::cout << delSpaces(str1);
delete[] str1;
```

A better option would be to change the `delSpaces()` function to take a `std::string` by reference instead:

```
void delSpaces(std::string &str) {
    size_t j = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < str.size(); ++i) {
        if (str[i] != ' ')
            str[j++] = str[i];
    }
    str.resize(j);
}

...

std::string s;
std::cin >> s;
delSpaces(s);
```

You can even let the STL remove the space characters for you:

```
void delSpaces(std::string &str) {
    str.erase(
        std::remove(str.begin(), str.end(), ' '),
        str.end()
    );
}
```

That being said, note that by default, when `operator>>` is reading character data, it ignores leading whitespace and then stops reading when it encounters whitespace, so your use of `operator>>` in this situation will *never* return a `std::string` that has spaces in it, thus your `delSpaces()` function is pretty useless as shown.  Use `std::getline()` instead, which reads until it encounters a line break, and thus can return a string with spaces in it:

```
std::getline(std::cin, s);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
char str1[]=s;
```

is not valid C++.

I recommend changing your function to take a `string` argument by reference.

But if you can't do that, then one way to get read/write access to the `char` buffer of non-`const` `s`, since C++11, is

```
&s[0]
```

Since C++17 you can also use `s.data()`.

However, note that your `delSpaces` creates a zero-terminated string in the supplied buffer, without knowing anything about a `string`. Since a `string` can hold any binary data `s.length()` would be unaffected by the call to `delSpaces`. You could fix that by adding a call to `s.resize()`, but again, a better approach is to express `delSpaces` with a `string&` argument.

Comment: `s.data()` (since C++17).

Comment: Isn't std::string now always null-terminated?

Comment: Yes, that's always well-defined, isn't it?

Comment: @NeilButterworth: It may be that I need even more coffee, yes, thanks. However I'm not sure about this now...

Comment: `s[s.size()]` is valid in C++11: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at

Comment: Though directly changing editing `s.data()` to a string with different length, as `delSpaces` does, is definitely not recommended

Comment: Uhm, I'm cleaning up the answer. Thanks everybody. :)

Comment: Have you seen the comment from @Justin ? I don't see how it is possibly undefined in C++11.